# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch <project directory>

Tags: android, react-native, node-modules

I have created new `React Native` project and trying to run it on android simulator, but when i write commane `react-native start`, it is showing following errors.

```
Loading dependency graph...(node:9088) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOSPC: no space left on device, watch '<project path>'
at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:161:26)
at Object.watch (fs.js:1218:11)
at NodeWatcher.watchdir (<project path>/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:175:20)
at new NodeWatcher (<project path>/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:45:8)
at createWatcher (<project path>/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:762:23)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at HasteMap._watch (<project path>/node_modules/jest-haste-map/build/index.js:912:44)
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? I have created 2 project with the same setup, one is working fine but other one is giving this kind of error.

```
react: 16.4.1
react-native:0.56.0
OS:ubuntu 16.04
```

Answer (score 2):

> To solve ENOSPC issue run following commands on Ubuntu

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p

sysctl --system
```

> For Arch Linux update below line in /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf file

```
fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
```

> After this run

```
sysctl --system
```